# RockPi (okdo rock 4c plus) camera setup

Tags: raspberry-pi, embedded, camera

This alternative to raspberry pi showed up and since all the Pi's are sold out I thought I would try it. https://www.okdo.com/p/okdo-rock-4-model-c-4gb-single-board-computer-rockchip-rk3399-t-arm-cortex-a72-cortex-a53/

However, cannot for the life of me find how to attach a camera. The regular rock 4 SE appear to have the same connectors as the regular pi but rock 4c+ has nothing. I have looked everywhere and their support, while they answer occasionally, seem to have no idea. According to specs on the webpage the regular Pi cam should be working but no such luck. The only CSI i find has a configuration I have never seen. Surely it could not attach to the DSI? Does anyone have any experience?

layout according to their support:

[image]
Note that the CSI appear to be a connector I have never seen before. The dsi (I understand this as a display port) look like the mipi 22 connector like PiZero's but I am not sure.

EDIT: After much searching I finally found this post on a forum by a different manufacturer. It looks like you need a special cable that is out of stock (##¤%#%&#¤ loud swearing on my part): https://forum.radxa.com/t/camera-cable-adapter-for-rock-pi-4c-plus/15093
You need a 0.3mm pitch to 1mm pitch 15PIN FPC cable
**I hope that someone here has some experience and perhaps can recommend an alternative.**

Comment: Can’t you use a USB camera?

Comment: It says this on the link: 1 x camera port (2‑lane MIPI CSI) <-- however, it's likely your question is off-topic for this site.

Comment: No, I'd prefer not to because I like the small footprint of the pi camera and the bloody specs claims I should be able to use one. And I don't have a small usb camera that I can spare for this project.
@Andy aka : Any idea where I should post? The question was booted from the Pi stack